# C++, может ли объект пользовательского класса заменить член типа `uint8_t`?

Tags: c++

Рассмотрим следующую структуру:

```
struct Message
{
    // ...
    uint8_t code;
    // ...
};
```

Предположим, что данная структура используется на границе `DLL`. То есть, через границу `DLL` передаются указатели на такие структуры.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем.

Могу ли я внутри `DLL` (или снаружи, но не с обеих сторон одновременно) определить новый тип-класс `Code` и работать с соответствующим полем через этот тип?

Например:

```
class Code
{
    public:
    // ...
    private:
    uint8_t value;
};

struct Message
{
    // ...
    Code code;
    // ...
};
```

Если класс `Code` содержит в себе только один единственный член, который занимает ровно один байт, могу ли я использовать тип `Code` вместо `uint8_t` внутри `Message`?

Я спрашиваю об этом потому, что было бы очень удобно, иметь специальный тип, в котором имеется набор `constexpr` констант и логика работы с объектом.

Comment: Интересно, что по этому поводу говорит `Стандарт`.

Comment: Так меня интересует не конкретно `DLL`, а сама возможность заменить элементарный тип - пользовательским. И затем сделать нечто, очень близкое к каламбуру типизации.

Comment: Так ведь нарушение strict aliasing вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, совершенно верно, но если код находится в `DLL`, то ситуация несколько иная. Главное, на мой взгляд, чтобы размер и расположение данных в памяти соответствовали друг другу по обе стороны интерфейса. Никто не запрещает передавать в `DLL` извне `uint32_t`, а внутри эти данные читать, как `float`. Ведь в `DLL` нет никакой информации о сигнатурах. Я говорю про `export "C"`.

Comment: Если я неправ, то поправьте меня.

Comment: Вроде все так, да. Формально UB, а на практике компилятор его не увидит.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, то есть, так делать можно?

Comment: Формально - нельзя. :) На практике, если работает, то можно.